# I am not able to get inner content of Div because contents are not literal

Tags: html, c#-4.0

I have a master page and a content page. I am creating menu dynamically. For this I have defined a div "`sidebar-menu`" in the Master Page as following:

```html
 <div id="sidebar-menu" runat="server">
  </div>
```

I want to access div "`sidebar-menu"` in the code behind and want to append the menu with the "`sidebar-menu`" InnerHTML property. 
However, as long as the page is loaded "`sidebar-menu`". InnerText property throws an exception of Type

> System.Web.HTTP.HTTPExtension

I want to know as why the InnerText property throws an exception immediately before I access it as the page is loaded?

I have searched a bit and applied most of the solutions but still not able to resolve this issue. Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: What does the exception say?

Answer (score 0):

I an not been able to find the reason of "Contents of the Div are not literal" but i found an alternative way to append the menu to div "sidebar-menu" in the code behind.

I have created a method in the code behind that creates the markup of the menu using "Response.Write" as follows.

```
public void RenderMenu()
{
    Response.Write("<li>");
    Response.Write("<a href='#'><i class='glyph-icon flaticon-email'></i><span class='sidebar-text'>Email</span><span class='fa arrow'></span></a>");
    Response.Write("<ul class='submenu collapse'>");
    Response.Write("<li><a href='mailbox.html'><span class='sidebar-text'>Inbox</span></a></li>");
    Response.Write("<li><a href='email_compose.html'><span class='sidebar-text'>Write a Message</span></a></li>");
    Response.Write("</ul>");
    Response.Write("</li>");
}
```

*Note:* For the case of simplicity I have not shown the code accessing database; since the method "RenderMenu" is written in the code behind we can create menu dynamically quite easily.

I then called this method in the Div "sidebar-menu" as follows

```
<div id="sidebar-menu" runat="server"> <%RenderMenu();%>  </div>
```

This successfully creates the dynamic menu.